# set day and month date in rechart xaxis

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, recharts

so i have this data:

```
const pulseAverage:[
    {
          name:'Pulse Average',
          style:'#5FE3A1',
          category:'Pulse Average',
          id:'right',
          data: [
            { day: '23/05/2020 04:50', value: 80 },
            { day: '24/05/2020 04:50', value: 83 },
            { day: '25/05/2020 04:50', value: 65 },
            { day: '26/05/2020 04:50', value: 72 },
            { day: '27/05/2020 04:50', value: 79 },
            { day: '28/05/2020 04:50', value: 93 },
            { day: '29/05/2020 04:50', value: 96 },
            { day: '30/05/2020 04:50', value: 91 },
            { day: '31/05/2020 04:50', value: 46 },
          ]
        }
```

i have successfully created a bar chart using it and it looks great. however, i have looked up on different stack overflow questions,github issues for a solution and i still can't find anything and sorry if you saw this question before but i'm really desperate for help. my problem is that i need the xaxis to display only the day/month like this and ignore the rest of the information. i need recharts to understand on its xaxis that i only need to display these two( ex: 29/05   30/05   31/05  ...)

code:

```
<BarChart
        width={1000}
        height={300}
        data={pulseAverage}
        margin={{
          top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="5 0" tickSize={15} />
        <XAxis 
        dataKey="day"  type="category"  tickLine={false} 
        axisLine={false}  dx={-15} allowDuplicatedCategory={false}
        />
        <YAxis yAxisId="left" orientation="left" dataKey="value" type="number" tickLine={false} axisLine={false} allowDuplicatedCategory={false}/>
        <YAxis yAxisId="right" orientation="right" dataKey="value" type="number" tickLine={false} axisLine={false} allowDuplicatedCategory={false}/>
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend 
        layout="horizontal" verticalAlign="top" align="center" 
        payload={
            pulseAverage.map(
            item => ({
              type: "circle",
              id: item.name,
              color: item.style,
              value: `${item.category}`
            })
          )
        }/>
        {pulseAverage.map(s => (
          <Bar yAxisId={s.id} barSize={10} dataKey="value" data={s.data} key={s.name} name={s.name} fill={s.style}/>          
       ))}
      </BarChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to split the date and reformat it according to your need.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    let dateTimeSplitted = date.split(' ')[0]   // Output: 23/05/2020
    let dateSplitted = dateTimeSplitted.split('/') // Output: ['23','05','2020']
    return dateSplitted[0]+ '/' + dateSplitted[1]  // Returns 23/05
}
```